# Unity JS - simple if statements not behaving as expected?

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a simple script (please no remarks on the fact that I'm not using a switch statement or better code, this is the earliest version and written this way by a peer, I am improving it) that takes an object and moves it back and forth. For some reason, the variable `time` gets stuck at 249. It is probably an obvious bug with this inefficient logic, but I cannot seem to find it.

```
var speed = 1;
private var time = 0;

function Start() {
}

function Update() {
    if(condition == true)moveStuff();
}

function moveStuff() {
    var timeSwitch = false;
    if(time == 0)timeSwitch = false;
    if(time == timeSet)timeSwitch = true;

        if(direction == 1) {
            if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log(time);
                }else if(timeSwitch == true) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                    Debug.Log(time);
                }   
            } else if(direction == 2) {
            if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.down * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log("Moved down. ");
                }else if(timeSwitch == true){
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.down * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                }
            } else if(direction == 3) {
                if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log("Moved forward. ");
                }else if(timeSwitch == true){
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                }
            } else if(direction == 4) {
                if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log("Moved back. ");
                }else if(timeSwitch == true){
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                }
            } else if(direction == 5) {
                if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log("Moved right. ");
                }else if(timeSwitch == true){
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                }
            } else if(direction == 6) {
                if(timeSwitch == false) {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (Time.deltaTime * speed));
                    time += 1;
                    Debug.Log("Moved left. ");
                }else if(timeSwitch == true){
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * ((Time.deltaTime * speed) * -1));
                    time -= 1;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code there in relation to your issue. Look at why the bool condition might get stuck and stop calling moveStuff().

Comment: Once the condition is true (set by another script), it never changes.

Comment: You've got to fix the indentation. It's impossible to read the code right now, and the bug is probably hiding there in the indentation. In particular, line 5 and 16 of moveStuff are indented incorrectly, and I can't tell if that's by mistake, or because that's the way you think it's executing.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I copied that part from another script I wrote in the project because I'm lazy, and the copy-paste on my computer is kind of screwy. Especially in the Unity script editor, for some reason. I definitely know it's not executing that way. That probably comes from all the Ruby I've been doing in school - `else` and `elsif` statements are indented within the block in Ruby.

Comment: That is impossible. There is no other script affecting this object.

Comment: It is absolutely, logically, impossible.

Comment: Don't start being rude, man.

Answer (score 0):

I had been declaring the variable `timeSet` as false each time at the beginning of `moveStuff()`. I moved that as a private var up to the area where I declared my other things and it worked perfectly.